# style.css is not picked up by index.php

Tags: html, css

I have an index.php html/php script and a style.css script in the same folder. Why does index.php not pick up the style.css script. Whatever changes I make to style.css have not effect on the browser when I put localhost/phplessons in the browser. Can someone please help? I much appreciate help on this.

```
chh1@chh1:/var/www/html/phplessons$ ls
calculator.php  index.php  style.css
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php
    $dayofweek = date("w");
    switch ($dayofweek) {
      case 1:
        echo "It is Monday!";
        break;
        case 2:
          echo "It is Tuesday!";
          break;
          case 3:
            echo "It is Wednesday!";
            break;
            case 4:
              echo "It is Thursday!";
              break;
              case 5:
                echo "It is Friday!";
                break;
                case 6:
                  echo "It is Saturday!";
                  break;
                  case 0:
                    echo "It is Sunday!";
                    break;
    }
   ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: 38vh;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your css is targeting `<p>` elements and you have none.

Comment: Sorry, your question has been answered, but wouldn't it be easier to just do `echo 'It is '.date('l');`, or if you really want to convert day number to name, to use an array `$names=['Sunday','Monday',...]; echo 'It is '.$names[$dayofweek];`?

Comment: Probably Gabriel. But this is just part of a learning tutorial. I am just a beginner at this stage. But thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML file would be picking up the style.css, however the CSS is defining the `<p></p>` tag which is not being used in your HTML code.

Consider adding `<p></p>` around your echo statements.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Gotcha. I  replaced `echo "It is Friday!";` with `echo "<p>It is Friday!</p>"` and it works fine. Thanks for that.